# JQuery replace function query

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Can anyone tell me why the following might remove the number 0 from the variable?

```
description = $("#description").val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

It replaces line breaks with the `<br />` perfectly but also removes 0!

Thanks
Rory

Comment: It doesn't. The error must be somewhere else in your code. Can you give us some more information?

Comment: Aaaah, I checked my MySQL and I was messing up that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore this question, completely wrong end of the stick!